# Import code style to Eclipse using Gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle, gradle-eclipse

For the sake of code style consistency I'd like to apply a set of formatting rules and save actions automatically to my Eclipse project.

I have encapsulated these rules in an [EPF file](http://pastebin.com/8DtB7itV) using `File > Export > Preferences` in Eclipse.

Is there a way to import this EPF file to Eclipse using Gradle to make the rules effective?
Gradle's [Eclipse Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseProject.html) has the `linkedResource` attribute but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

Any hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: Can not help you with your actual question directly (on how to handle this using gradle), I can however suggest to have a look at https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic. We have been using it quite some time, and it works fluently. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no feature to import these settings automatically in Gradle. However, I could think about building something manually by providing a `defaultJdtPrefs.properties` file which contains all the settings for `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`. For creating `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` while executing `gradle eclipse` you could use the following:

```
tasks.cleanEclipse.doLast {
    delete("${project.projectDir}/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs")
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    File saveActionPrefs = file("${project.projectDir}/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs")
    if (saveActionPrefs.exists()) {
        logger.warn("UI preferences already exist and will not be overridden. Use task 'cleanEclipse' first.")
    } else {
        saveActionPrefs.append('''
             eclipse.preferences.version=1
             <<HERE COMES YOUR CONTENT>>
             '''. stripIndent())
    }
}
```

With this solution you could even the above provided EPF file containing the your preferences to create the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` file using any of the Groovy build-in XML parsers ;-)

I know this is not the best solution because you have to add these things to every project (or via a custom Gradle plugin), though, the only solution I can currently think of.